# Finding the highest power of N to fit in a given power of 2

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find the highest power $p$ of a number $N$ that will fit in a given power of 2. To give this some context, I am trying to find the largest power of $N$ that will fit in a 64-bit signed integer without overflow. I have calculated (programmatically) the highest power $p$ that will fit in a 32-bit signed integer, and now I want to (if possible) find the largest power of $N$ that will fit in a 64-bit signed integer mathematically.

I have attempted to solve this problem in the following manner:

Let $q$ be the size in bits of the signed integer. In this case since I have calculated the largest power of $N$ to fit in a 32 bit signed integer, $q = 32$. The following inequality should hold:

$$N^p < 2^{q-1} - 1 < N^{p+1}$$

Now since I want to find the highest power to fit in a 64-bit signed integer, I try to manipulate $2^{q-1} - 1$ to be of the form $2^{2q-1} - 1$.

$$N^p + 1 < 2^{q-1} < N^{p+1}$$

$$2[N^p + 1] < 2^q < 2[N^{p+1}]$$

$$2^{q+1}[N^p + 1] < 2^{2q} < 2^{q+1}[N^{p+1}]$$

$$2^{q}[N^p + 1] < 2^{2q-1} < 2^{q}[N^{p+1}]$$

$$2^{q}[N^p + 1] - 1 < 2^{2q-1} - 1 < 2^{q}[N^{p+1}] - 1$$

At this point I am unsure of how to proceed. I want to get the equation in some form that I can calculate for some $N$ that if $q = 32$ and $p$ equals some constant $c$ then when $q = 64$ I can calculate the highest power of $N$ based on $c$.

I am not sure if I am taking the right approach at this problem either. Any help setting me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this will relate to the $\log$ base $N$ of the power of two, $2^k$.

Comment: I think this is just related to $N^q=2^{64}$, so $q=\frac{64}{\log_2 N}$ will be the closest real number to your desired $p\in\Bbb N$, Im not sure now but possibly it will be $p=\lfloor q\rfloor$.